# Using QWebEngine to login to a SAML authorization page, wait for a cookie, and then cleanup / exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to write a PyQT QWebEngineView that opens a website, does a SAML login to AAD, returns, and once it sees a specific cookie (openconnect webvpn cookie), grabs the value and returns it to the "console" script which can continue processing and/or return to the command prompt.

I've glued together enough code that I can pop a browser window, step through my SAML authorization and see the cookie and cookie value. I don't know how to auto-close / exit the WebView window and "return" that cookie value and/or just the array to Python itself so I can keep processing it and/or exit. Not quite sure how to "clean up" my objects either.

I did probably fudge up my classes, initiators, and object variables. It's a kludge.

Thoughts? Ideas?

This is Arch Linux with latest Python and pyqt via package repo.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#core python
import sys

#PyQT libraries
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

#functions / classes
class OpenconnectSamlAuth(QMainWindow):
   #init self object
   def __init__(self):
      #inherit parents functions, classes, etc....
      super(OpenconnectSamlAuth, self).__init__()

      #create webview object
      self.webview = QWebEngineView()

      #grab profile
      self.profile = QWebEngineProfile("storage", self.webview)
      self.cookie_store = self.profile.cookieStore()
      self.cookie_store.cookieAdded.connect(self.onCookieAdded)

      #empty array of cookies
      self.samlcookies = []

      #set some window options
      #window width x height
      self.resize(1024, 768);

      #default settings
      self.mySettings = QWebEngineSettings.defaultSettings()
      self.mySettings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)


   #load URL / process login
   def samlLogin(self,url):
      #create page and load URL
      webpage = QWebEnginePage(self.profile, self.webview)
      self.webview.setPage(webpage)
      self.webview.load(QUrl(url))

      #windows options
      self.setCentralWidget(self.webview)

      #window title
      self.webview.setWindowTitle('Loading...')
      self.webview.titleChanged.connect(self.updateTitle)


   #update title window       
   def updateTitle(self):
      self.webview.setWindowTitle(self.webview.title())


   #handle cookies being added
   def onCookieAdded(self, cookie):
      #check if cookies exists
      #for c in self.cookies:
      #   if c.hasSameIdentifier(cookie):
      #      return
      #self.cookies.append(QNetworkCookie(cookie))      return;
      #bytearray(c.name()).decode()
      print(bytearray( QNetworkCookie(cookie).name() ).decode() )
      print(bytearray( QNetworkCookie(cookie).value() ).decode() )
      return
         

#main loop
def main():
   #initialize QT application object
   App = QApplication(sys.argv)

   #setup webkit window / browser session
   OpenconnectWebObj = OpenconnectSamlAuth()

   #load URL
   OpenconnectWebObj.samlLogin("https://vpnserverurl/groupname")

   #show connection window
   OpenconnectWebObj.show()

   #execute the app and grab the returned cookie
   cookie = App.exec_()
   print(cookie)

   #exit
   sys.exit()


#if called via command line; run this
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: I don't know what function / class object calls I need to make to get that QMainWindow object to close from "inside" itself and while it's closing how to pass a cookie back to the "main" python loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the window then you must call the close() method, but in this case it seems that it requires terminating the Qt eventloop so the QCoreApplication.quit() method should be used. On the other hand, the cookie can be stored as an attribute and then used:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import (
    QWebEnginePage,
    QWebEngineProfile,
    QWebEngineSettings,
    QWebEngineView,
)


class OpenconnectSamlAuth(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(OpenconnectSamlAuth, self).__init__(parent)

        self._cookie = None

        self.webview = QWebEngineView()

        self.profile = QWebEngineProfile("storage", self.webview)
        self.cookie_store = self.profile.cookieStore()
        self.cookie_store.cookieAdded.connect(self.handle_cookie_added)

        self.profile.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)

        webpage = QWebEnginePage(self.profile, self)
        self.webview.setPage(webpage)
        self.webview.titleChanged.connect(self.update_title)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.webview)
        self.resize(1024, 768)

    @property
    def cookie(self):
        return self._cookie

    def login(self, url):
        self.webview.load(QUrl.fromUserInput(url))
        self.webview.setWindowTitle("Loading...")

    def update_title(self):
        self.webview.setWindowTitle(self.webview.title())

    def handle_cookie_added(self, cookie):
        print("added {name} : {value}".format(name=cookie.name(), value=cookie.value()))
        if cookie.name() == b"name_of_cookie":
            self._cookie = QNetworkCookie(cookie)
            QCoreApplication.quit()


# main loop
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    openconnect_webobj = OpenconnectSamlAuth()
    openconnect_webobj.login("https://vpnserverurl/groupname")
    openconnect_webobj.show()

    ret = app.exec_()

    cookie = openconnect_webobj.cookie
    if cookie is not None:
        print("results:", cookie.name(), cookie.value(), cookie.toRawForm())

    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with it tomorrow and see how it goes. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @HenrikHudson  If answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Yeap. Just rolled out of bed. Adding the `QCoreApplication.quit()` and the cookie to the object itself and accessing via a object function worked fine. Thanks again.