# Disable caching or clear cache with QtWebEngine

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have been using a slightly adapted version of the `OpenconnectSamlAuth` class that has been shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694690/9640238), with PyQT5.

Now, I'd like to either clear the cache or disable it entirely. I have to admit that the code is a bit opaque to me (I'm not familiar with PyQT), and I couldn't find any relevant setting [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html) either.

Any hint?

Comment: There is `QWebEngineProfile::clearHttpCache()`